How can I perform a hierarchical query with the AWS CLI for specific tags and output the result in a flat structure?
With the following query:
aws fsx describe-file-systems \
  --no-paginate --no-cli-pager --output yaml \
  --query 'FileSystems[].{id:FileSystemId,netid:NetworkInterfaceIds[0],name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value}'

the output lists the result of the search in the tags in an extra level of hierarchy:
- id: fs-1234abcd
  name:
  - home
  netid: eni-1234abcde

I would like to have a flat structure like this:
- id: fs-1234abcd
  name: home
  netid: eni-1234abcde

This would make it easier to display a table of objects or do further queries. I tried the usual flatten operator [] but that wouldn't remove that extra level.

Inspired by this answer, I now got it:
aws fsx describe-file-systems \
  --no-paginate --no-cli-pager --output yaml \
  --query 'FileSystems[].{id:FileSystemId,netid:NetworkInterfaceIds[0],name:Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value|[0]}'

I tried adding the [0] to dereference the first element of the resulting list of one tag, but then the query returned (null). Adding the pipe | does the trick.
The manual states that

A pipe-expression stops projections on the left hand side for propagating to the right hand side. If the left expression creates a projection, it does not apply to the right hand side.

If I understand this correctly, because I did a query of the Tags[?...] I created a projection. To get the first element of it, I've got to stop the projection from propagating with the |, and then refer to the first element with [0].
